# How does CBIR work with SVM instead of Euclidean distance?

Tags: svm, cbir

Generally CBIR works with Euclidean distance for comparing a query image and a database image feature vectors.

However in math works, I got a source code that instead of Euclidean distance it is done with SVM, like a content based image retrieval using two techniques:

1. Using knn for image retrieval;
2. Using svm for image retrieval.

How does it work?

Answer (score 0):

There are some literature in that area:

[Content Based Image Retrieval Using SVM Algorithm](http://interscience.in/IJEEE_Vol1Iss3/Paper7.pdf)

[An Approach for Image Retrieval Using SVM](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4614-3872-4_37?no-access=true)

[Image Retrieval with Structured Object Queries Using Latent Ranking SVM](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~mori/research/papers/lan-eccv12.pdf)

As far as I know, the simple approach is having a feature extraction phase (i.e Using PCA) and then doing a [one-class svm](http://rvlasveld.github.io/blog/2013/07/12/introduction-to-one-class-support-vector-machines/) classification.

K-NN usually uses euclidean distance anyway so the algorithm is offering you a more consistent decision boundary and a feature extraction phase on top of that. You can see an example [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.4717)